# Interpreting the Horvitz–Thompson estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I Have an experiment which is randomizing across time in hourly granularity. Each hour has probability of 1/2 of being in either control or treatment. Suppose the I am interested in the expectation of random variable $X$ in control vs treatment, and the following is an example of a realization of samples:

`{0, T, 1.5}, {1, T, 2},  {2, C, 3}, {3, C, 3}, {4, T, 5.5}`

where each tuple {0, T, 1.5} means that at hour 0, it is treatment, and observed value for X is 1.5. If I just take a Naive average then treatment average of $X$ is 3 whereas the control average of $X$ is 3. If I use the [Horvitz–Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator) estimator then for the treatment we have $(1.5 * 2 + 2 * 2 + 5.5 * 2) / 5 = 3.6$ assuming that there are only 5 hours in a day and for the control we have $(3 * 2 + 3 * 2) / 5 = 2.4$. How to interpret the difference between the two averages?

Comment: $(1.5 \times 2 + 2 \times 2)/4 = (3 + 4)/4 = 7/4 = 1.75$, so the answer is you've done something weird in your arithmetic and it isn't the estimator's fault.

Comment: My apology and I corrected the example.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two estimates is the way they account for different possible mixtures of the two subgroups (treatment and control).

Essentially, you have a population of 10 possible measurements, since in each hour there is a theoretical measurement for either treatment or control. In other words, the whole population looks something like this (including our observed measurements):

| Hour | Treatment | Control |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T0 = 1.5 | C0 = ? |
| 1 | T1 = 2 | C1 = ? |
| 2 | T2 = ? | C2 = 3 |
| 3 | T3 = ? | C3 = 3 |
| 4 | T4 = 5.5 | C4 = ? |

We can imagine that the measurements we observe are actually of two variables - $y_T$ and $y_C$, where $y_C = 0$ for all of the measurements from the treatment group and $y_T = 0$ for all of the measurements from the control group. When you calculate the Horvitz-Thompson estimator, then, it's assuming that the distribution of $y_T$ is "fair" across the measurements you haven't observed - and as a result, because 60% of the observed measurements come from treatment groups, it's extrapolating to assume that the unobserved measurements are also about 60% treatment. Obviously we know this isn't correct - in fact, we know that the unobserved measurements actually belong 60% to the *control* group.

In other words, when a subgroup is over-represented in the sample, its contribution will be over-represented in the H-T estimate as well. We can see that even more simply by noticing that if we calculate the H-T estimate of the population total of treatment and control measurements (i.e. calculate the totals of the variables that are 1 when the value comes from that group and 0 otherwise) - we similarly get a result that the population is apparently 60% treatment measurements and 40% control, as opposed to the 50/50 split we know it to be.

The H-T estimator is a linear unbiased estimator, but it is not necessarily the most efficient estimator if we can bring additional information into play. We can correct for the over-representation of treatment measurements in our sample by, for example, rescaling the estimate. There are various ways we can do this, and one way is to use an estimator called the *domain estimator* - we estimate the mean of a variable for a given subgroup by calculating the H-T estimate of the total of that variable, and then divide it by the H-T estimate of the size of that subgroup's population. That way, if the subgroup is over-represented in the sample, both the numerator and denominator will be inflated by a similar factor so it will (roughly) cancel out.

If you calculate the domain estimator for the mean of the treatment group, it looks something like this:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \hat{\bar{y}}_{d1} & = & \frac{\hat{y}_{d\pi}}{\hat{n}_{d\pi}} \\
& = & \frac{2 \times 1.5 + 2 \times 2 + 2 \times 0 + 2 \times 0 + 2 \times 5.5}
{2 \times 1 + 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 0 + 2 \times 0 + 2 \times 1} \\
& = & \frac{18}{6} \\
& = & 3
\end{eqnarray}$$

and if you do the same for the control group, you'll get a similar result. In fact, for this particular sample design, the domain estimate of the mean will be *exactly* the same as what you get when calculating the naive averages, as long as you always have at least one treatment and one control measurement. That won't be the case if, for example, you have unequal probabilities of going to either group in each hour.

There are various other ways to adjust the estimator, and most of the obvious choices will wind up doing something similar. They will usually result in an estimator that is more *efficient* than the Horvitz-Thompson (i.e. has a smaller mean squared error), at the expense of either being non-linear or introducing some amount of bias, or both.